# Реализация сравнения X с элементом "i" и "i+1"

Tags: python, циклы

Есть задача вставить "X" в отсортированный массив. 
В python это можно реализовать с помощью "bisect.insort(m, x)", но нужна реализация через циклы.

И тут возникают трудности, т.к. ранее в python не работал.

Upd1: В данный момент сравнение X с элементом i реализуется через:

```
import random

print('Введите X:')
x = int(input())

# Генерация списка случайных числел и его сортировка
m = [int(random.randint(1, 40)) for i in range(0, 20)]
m.sort()

print('Отсортированный список: ', m)
print('Длина списка', len(m))

# Вставка эл-та в отсортированный список
for i, val in enumerate(m):
    try:
        if x > val and x < m[i+1]:
            m.insert(x, m)
    except IndexError:
        pass

print('Итоговый список: ', m)
print('Длина списка', len(m))
```

и сейчас он ругается на:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/PLT/main.py", line 17, in <module>
if x > val and x < m[i+1]:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > list()
```

Comment: дополнил свой ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так например:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
x = 5
for index, value in enumerate(a):
    try:
        if x > value and x < a[index + 1]:
            print(a[index], x, a[index + 1], True)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

**UPD:** неправильно применяете операцию вставки:
`insert(индекс_куда_вставлять, элемент_который_нужно_вставить)`

```
m = [28, 15, 20, 37, 23, 15, 33, 37, 1, 19, 14, 7, 28, 36, 32, 8, 12, 36, 37, 5]
m.sort()
# [1, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14, 15, 15, 19, 20, 23, 28, 28, 32, 33, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37]
x = 22
for index, value in enumerate(m):
    try:
        if x > value and x < m[index + 1]:
            m.insert(index + 1, x)
            break
    except IndexError:
        pass
# [1, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14, 15, 15, 19, 20, 22 - сюда встал x, 23, 28, 28, 32, 33, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

x = int(input('Введите X:'))
m = sorted(list(random.randint(1, 40) for _ in range(0, 20)))

for a in m:
    if x < a:
        m.insert(m.index(a), x)
        break
else:  # x > max(m)
    m.append(x)

# if x > val and x < m[i+1]: - записать так можно:
# if m[i+1] < val < x:
```